# Implementing Non -Renewable subscriptions Using MKstorekit4?

Tags: iphone

I have Iphone application in which i wanted to use Non_Renewable subscriptions.As per docs MKstorekit supports Non Renewable subscriptions.But everywhere saying about Auto_renewables only.Can anybody knows how to implement Non-renewable subscription with MKstorekit4.I have been googling for the entire day.But with no luck.Can anybody help me ?Was anybody done this kind of in app with mkstorekit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In non renewing subscriptions we need to use the server tracking .In non renewing subscriptions you will get a receipt data containing some purchase details with purchase date,store the receipt in your server and calculate the expiration date from the purchase date and use this server tracking to show your buying view again,you need to store the receipt corresponding with the user details to get this on all the devices the user is using